# YouTube custom setting parameters for UIWebView CGRectMake not populating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am having an issue with a custom setting parameters for UIWebView I have tried a hundred diff ways.. But it keeps going under my navigation bar at the top and it also goes a inch or so past the bottom of the scroll. I am trying to use CGRectMake but it is not populating anything.

```
 @interface songVideoViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation songVideoViewController

 @synthesize tubeName;
 @synthesize webVPrg;

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
 //webVPrg = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
 [super viewDidLoad];
 _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
 _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
 _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];
// Set the Label text with the selected recipe

 NSArray *bossConverter = [tubeName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

NSString *bossInput = [bossConverter componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];

webVPrg = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:([NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%@&oq=%@&v2", bossInput, bossInput])];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//webVPrg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
webVPrg.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:webVPrg];
[webVPrg loadRequest:request];


}
```